# Modify a text field dynamically. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive, in which I click on a field and then I can edit it. To this directive I can add a property called "typeinput". If typeinput = "textarea" then I would like the dynamic field to be a textarea and not an input text. I'm doing this validation with the help of an ng-if.

[image]

But if I do this this stops working, and the new dynamic field value is not saved. How can i fix it?

```
<div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
      <a  href='' click-to-edit  ng-model='faq.pregunta'   typeinput='textarea' >{{faq.pregunta}}</a>
</div>

    .directive('clickToEdit', function($timeout,$compile) {

      return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          scope: {
              model: '=ngModel'
          },
          replace: true,
          transclude: false,
          // includes our template
          template:
              '<div class="templateRoot">'+
                  '<div class="hover-edit-trigger" title="click to edit">'+
                      '<div class="hover-text-field" ng-show="!editState" ng-click="toggle()">{{model}}</div>'+
                      //'<span ng-if="type==true">'+
                      '<input class="inputText" type="text" ng-model="localModel" ng-enter="save()" ng-show="editState" />' +
                      //'</span>'+
                      //'<span ng-if="type==false">'+
                      //'<textarea class="inputText"  ng-model="localModel" ng-enter="save()" ng-show="editState" />' +
                      //'</span>'+
                      '<div class="edit-button-group pull-right" ng-show="editState">'+
                          '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"  ng-click="save()"></div>'+
                          '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="cancel()"></div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
              '</div>',
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ybmrzo5w/

Comment: Your plunker link is broken

Comment: plunker is not responding...wait me update the link..

Comment: @JeanJacques https://jsfiddle.net/ybmrzo5w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `ng-if` directive, like other directives creates a child scope.

You can use an object property in `ng-model` - then, even if `ng-if` creates the new child scope, the parent scope will have the changes: 
`localModel.value` should work in your case.

See the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz7gopoa/).

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `ngIf` it creates a child scope so in the `ngModel` of your textarea and your input you need to reference to the parent scope like this :

```
ng-model="$parent.localModel"
```